# How to create a public.pem and private.pem that contains only alphanumeric data?

Tags: encryption, cryptography, key-pair

I need to create a public.pem and private.pem but I need these 2 files data must contain only alphanumeric values.

Ex:

```
-----BEGIN PUBLIC KEY-----
YnSfHPKjSuR1qPBNWRgeIqBcvN98gJsAjsInjl5SGdpReRNOaUQS6NuCBZ4wcWZu
iGBpyoS5Xo0eFWQD16fQuzzS02VPRtUzAEcJBNJn1TrsqB9u2sz715RAp9Yij1LO
tRpIpeZeSrfV7rvM8SFSXbrQiwsPLrxJZt3ZPsyL8zIjArPoovbbwFdscdFdQGTg
SbomQA833dzsCEGj593eAZiyG2juBogRDKTKUxoJoiTw6qwxt1V0LsOgD31AVcHF
==
-----END PUBLIC KEY-----
```

Most of the example I look so far the public and the private key and contains alphanumeric values as well as "/#%@" type characters.

I need to create a public and the private key that contains only alphanumeric characters.

How to create a public.pem and private.pem that contains only alphanumeric data?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `/#%@` characters are [base64](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Base64), this is simply an encoding scheme for binary data and has no bearing on what the underlying data is.

With regard to having public/private keys that have an underlying structure that's alphanumeric, that's also impossible as:

Elliptic curve crypto-systems use:

- Numeric private keys, representing the scalar for ECC point multiplication.
- Numeric public keys, representing a point on a Cartesian plane.

RSA crypto-systems use:

- Numeric private keys, representing the private exponent value.
- Numeric public keys, representing a modulus and public exponent value.

There are no alpha values in either.